# How to save a uitextfield so the text remains from view controller to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, save, uitextfield, swift3

My text right now saves the textfield in a uiviewcontroller but when a go to the previous view controller than back to the original view controller the text is erased. How can I save the text so that when the text is entered and saved the text stays their.

```
import UIKit

class tryingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textext: UITextField!

    @IBAction func actionaction(_ sender: Any) {
        textext.resignFirstResponder()
        let myText = textext.text
        UserDefaults.standard.set(myText, forKey: "myKey")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options you could use.

1. Using CoreData
2. Saving the text in your main view controller
3. Storing it in `UserDefaults`

Seeing as you're already using `UserDefaults`, I'll just stick with it and show an example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

let standardText = "standardText"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    textField.text = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: standardText) as? String
}

func textDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.text ?? "", forKey: standardText)
}
```

Comment: A cautionary note on using UserDefaults to store sensitive information. https://www.andyibanez.com/nsuserdefaults-not-for-sensitive-data/

Comment: Good point in case OP wants to store sensitive data. I only created this example purely because OP was using it already and I have no idea what he wants to do with it :).

Answer (score -1):

You're setting the defaults but you're not reading back out of it:

```
if let string = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myKey") as? String {
     textext.text = string
}
```

Or as pointed out, since the textfields text is optional:

```
textext.text = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myKey") as? String
```

Comment: You don't even need checking if there is a string in the defaults as default text value of text field is null. Just do `textfield.text = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myKey") as? String`

Comment: @ozgur In this case, you are correct since `text` is optional.